# springboot container test failing for testcontainers/ryuk with docker engine 20.10

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker, testcontainers

I am working on springboot app where I am using testcontainers for database tests.

I am getting **{"message":"No such image: quay.io/testcontainers/ryuk:0.2.3"}** error for docker engine version 20.10.0 and higher. And it is working with version  **19.03.15**

Below are the configuration of my system

*docker engine version*

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.0
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        7287ab3
 Built:             Tue Dec  8 18:59:40 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.0
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       eeddea2
  Built:            Tue Dec  8 18:57:45 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.12
  GitCommit:        7b11cfaabd73bb80907dd23182b9347b4245eb5d
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.2
  GitCommit:        v1.0.2-0-g52b36a2
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

My configuration is as below

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>1.10.6</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Springboot class :

```
@TestConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class TestDatabaseInitializer
    implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext>, DisposableBean {

  @Container
  public static PostgreSQLContainer postgreSQLContainer =
      new PostgreSQLContainer("postgres:10.11")
          .withDatabaseName("report")
          .withUsername("test-user")
          .withPassword("test-password");

  @Override
  public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext) {
    postgreSQLContainer.start();

    TestPropertyValues.of(
        "spring.datasource.url=" + postgreSQLContainer.getJdbcUrl(),
        "spring.datasource.username=" + postgreSQLContainer.getUsername(),
        "spring.datasource.password=" + postgreSQLContainer.getPassword())
        .applyTo(configurableApplicationContext.getEnvironment());
  }

  @Override
  public void destroy() {
    if (postgreSQLContainer != null && postgreSQLContainer.isRunning()) {
      postgreSQLContainer.stop();
    }
  }
}
```

Now when I run `mvn clean test` it gives me following error.

```
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:142)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:383)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:344)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:125)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:417)
Caused by: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerFetchException: Can't get Docker image: RemoteDockerImage(imageNameFuture=java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture@5833f5cd[Completed normally], imagePullPolicy=DefaultPullPolicy(), dockerClient=LazyDockerClient.INSTANCE)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.getDockerImageName(GenericContainer.java:1265)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.logger(GenericContainer.java:600)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:311)
    ... 48 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.NotFoundException: {"message":"No such image: quay.io/testcontainers/ryuk:0.2.3"}

    at org.testcontainers.dockerclient.transport.okhttp.OkHttpInvocationBuilder.execute(OkHttpInvocationBuilder.java:279)
    at org.testcontainers.dockerclient.transport.okhttp.OkHttpInvocationBuilder.execute(OkHttpInvocationBuilder.java:263)
    at org.testcontainers.dockerclient.transport.okhttp.OkHttpInvocationBuilder.post(OkHttpInvocationBuilder.java:134)
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.exec.CreateContainerCmdExec.execute(CreateContainerCmdExec.java:33)
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.exec.CreateContainerCmdExec.execute(CreateContainerCmdExec.java:13)
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.exec.AbstrSyncDockerCmdExec.exec(AbstrSyncDockerCmdExec.java:21)
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.command.AbstrDockerCmd.exec(AbstrDockerCmd.java:35)
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.command.CreateContainerCmdImpl.exec(CreateContainerCmdImpl.java:1139)
    at org.testcontainers.utility.ResourceReaper.start(ResourceReaper.java:85)
    at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.client(DockerClientFactory.java:135)
    at org.testcontainers.LazyDockerClient.getDockerClient(LazyDockerClient.java:14)
    at org.testcontainers.LazyDockerClient.listImagesCmd(LazyDockerClient.java:12)
    at org.testcontainers.images.LocalImagesCache.maybeInitCache(LocalImagesCache.java:68)
    at org.testcontainers.images.LocalImagesCache.get(LocalImagesCache.java:32)
```

If I change my docker engine version from **20.10.*** to **19.03.15** then it is working fine.

I have install specific docker version using

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce=5:19.03.15~3-0~ubuntu-focal docker-ce-cli=5:19.03.15~3-0~ubuntu-focal
```

**Docker version :**
Client: Docker Engine - Community
Version:           19.03.15
API version:       1.40
Go version:        go1.13.15
Git commit:        99e3ed8919
Built:             Sat Jan 30 03:17:01 2021
OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
Experimental:      false

```
Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.15
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       99e3ed8919
  Built:            Sat Jan 30 03:15:30 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.12
  GitCommit:        7b11cfaabd73bb80907dd23182b9347b4245eb5d
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.2
  GitCommit:        v1.0.2-0-g52b36a2
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

With this version existing code is working without any error or any missing dependency, and it also download **quay.io/testcontainers/ryuk:0.2.3**

Comment: Certainly your dependency graph is not hydrated with the required docker image, maybe because it does not exists yet ? Curious bug. Did you read changelogs for breaking changes ?

Comment: @BendaThierry.com, If I try with lower version of docker then it is working wihout any changes. I don't see any breaking changes for docker release.

Comment: pre-pull the image and try again ```quay.io/testcontainers/ryuk:0.2.3```

Comment: You're using quite an old version of Testcontainers - can you update to `1.16.3` and run your tests again?

Comment: @RickRackow pre-pooling is working, but I am running my test on jenkins which is containerized and everytime it pulls the image so pre-pool only work on local.

Comment: @rieckpil I tried to update the testContainer but because of new docker engine it is not able to pull ryuk image.

Comment: There is an existing (closed) [issue](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/3574) for this on GitHub. It should be solved with Testcontainers > 1.15.1. If the provided solutions in this ticket don't work for you, I guess you should create a new issue and explain your setup. As a workaround, you can also pre pull the image on Jenkins, just add a `docker pull ...` step before running your tests.